trying to make a number corousel but it wont apply active class to the element based on the card index
i am trying to make a number corousel but it wont update the active class for specific values in the html.
i am using vue js creating a cards array
and duplicating for infinite scrolling effect
this is working as intended
and calculating the active index based on the scroll position
<template>
  <div class="wrapper" ref="onWrapper">
    <i @click="handleClick('top')" class="pi pi-angle-up"></i>
    <ul ref="onCorousel" class="corousel" @mousemove="dragging" @mousedown="dragStart" @mouseup="dragStop"
      @scroll="infiniteScroll" @mouseleave="dragStop">
      <li v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index" class="card" :class="{'active': card === this.cards[this.activeIndex]}">
        <div class="img">{{ card }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <i @click="handleClick('bottom')" class="pi pi-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [3, 4, 6, 8],
      activeIndex: 1,
      corousel: null,
      isDragging: false,
      startY: 0,
      startScrollTop: 0,
      firstCardHeight: null,
      corouselChildrens: null,
      cardPerView: null,
      maxCardHeight: null

    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.corousel = this.$refs.onCorousel
    this.corouselChildrens = [...this.corousel.children];
    const cardHeights = Array.from(this.corouselChildrens).map(card => card.offsetHeight);
    this.maxCardHeight = Math.max(...cardHeights);
    this.cardPerView = Math.floor(this.corousel.offsetHeight / this.maxCardHeight);
    this.corouselChildrens.slice(-this.cardPerView).reverse().forEach(card => {
      this.corousel.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", card.outerHTML)
    })

    this.corouselChildrens.slice(0, this.cardPerView).forEach(card => {
      this.corousel.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", card.outerHTML)
    })
    console.log(this.cards)
    console.log(this.corousel)

  },
  methods: {
    dragStart(e) {
      this.isDragging = true
      this.corousel.classList.add("dragging")
      this.startY = e.pageY;
      this.startScrollTop = this.corousel.scrollTop
    },
    dragStop() {
      this.isDragging = false
      this.corousel.classList.remove("dragging")


    },
    dragging(e) {
      if (!this.isDragging) return;
      const deltaY = e.pageY - this.startY;

    
      const newScrollTop = this.startScrollTop - deltaY;


      this.corousel.scrollTop = Math.max(0, Math.min(newScrollTop, this.corousel.scrollHeight - this.corousel.offsetHeight));
    },

    handleClick(id) {
      if (id === 'top') {
        this.corousel.scrollTop += -this.maxCardHeight
        if (this.activeIndex === 0) {
          this.activeIndex = 3
        }
        else {
          this.activeIndex -= 1
        }


      }
      if (id === 'bottom') {
        this.corousel.scrollTop += this.maxCardHeight
        if (this.activeIndex === 3) {
          this.activeIndex = 0
        }
        else {
          this.activeIndex += 1
        }
      }
      console.log(this.activeIndex)
      console.log(this.cards[this.activeIndex])





    },
    infiniteScroll: debounce(function () {
      if (this.corousel.scrollTop === 0) {
        console.log('top');
        this.corousel.classList.add("no-transition");
        this.corousel.scrollTop = this.corousel.scrollHeight - (2 * this.corousel.offsetHeight);
        this.corousel.classList.remove("no-transition");
      } else if (Math.ceil(this.corousel.scrollTop) === this.corousel.scrollHeight - this.corousel.offsetHeight) {
        this.corousel.classList.add("no-transition");
        this.corousel.scrollTop = this.corousel.offsetHeight;
        this.corousel.classList.remove("no-transition");
      }
    }, 100)
  }
}
</script>

<style>
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #031A9A, #8B53FF);
}

.wrapper {
  max-height: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper i {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(+100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)
}

.wrapper i:first-child {
  top: -22px;
}

.wrapper i:last-child {
  bottom: -22px;
}

.wrapper .corousel {
  height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-rows: calc((100% / 3) - 12px);
  gap: 16px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scrollbar-width: 0;
}

.corousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.corousel.no-transition {
  scroll-behavior: auto;

}

.corousel.dragging .card {
  cursor: grab;
  user-select: none;
}

.corousel.dragging {
  scroll-snap-type: none;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}

.corousel .card {

  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 100px;

}

.card .img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;

}

.card.active {
  /* transform: scale(1.2); */
  background-color: red;
}
</style>


on the handle click event it just wont apply background red the html would be like this sometimes
<ul class="corousel">
<li class="card active"><div class="img">4</div></li>
<li class="card"><div class="img">6</div></li>
<li class="card"><div class="img">8</div></li>
<li class="card"><div class="img">3</div></li>
<li class="card"><div class="img">4</div></li>
<li class="card"><div class="img">6</div></li>
<li class="card active"><div class="img">8</div></li>
<li class="card"><div class="img">3</div></li>
<li class="card active"><div class="img">4</div></li>
<li class="card"><div class="img">6</div></li>
</ul>

here the active class should be only one 8 but its not working as intended

Do not use this in the template aka this.cards[this.activeIndex] should be cards[activeIndex] in the :class part. There is a lot of code doing a lot of things. What exactly does not work here? Could you narrow down the issue by using the Vue devtools? Also, you do have the card class properly, right? Which one is missing then?

even if i use cards[activeIndex] it wont matter
the problem is that
when i click on top or bottom it will skip one number and wont apply the active class on it
like by clicking on top button
it will skip 8
and by clicking bottom it will skip 3

Was just a minor reminder. But yes, the problem might be elsewhere, hence the rest of my comment.

inserting new cards via manual manipulation of the DOM (insertAdjacentTML lines), is not going to work with Vue which is meant to manage the DOM for you.  The v-for is only looping through the cards in cards, it doesn't know about the card HTML you added manually.  Instead of creating and inserting new HTML into corouselChildrens, insert new card values into cards
